# Грамотная подсказка, как разместить камеру в Control Rig

Tags: unreal-engine-5

Ищу способ сделать такой-же риг, как на данном видео, обратите, пожалуйста, внимание с 5:06
Сокет в Меше уже имеется, в Control Rig добавил, нужного эффекта не получил.
Прошу помощи.

Конкретная проблема в том, что я добавил сокет под камеру, поместил в него камеру, дальше пошел в Control Rig, и не понимаю, откуда там такие координаты камеры как на видео.

[Видео из ютуба](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14pk6-MXi_4&t=428s)

[image: То место где не понимаю, как достичь такого-же эффекта как на видео]

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Глеб Конкретная проблема в том, что я добавил сокет под камеру, поместил в него камеру, дальше пошел в Control Rig, и не понимаю, откуда там такие координаты камеры как на видео

Comment: @Глеб Не понимаю, для чего отвечать, если ты не готов отвечать, нужно репортить таких, чтобы не набивали посты.

Comment: Вы не понимаете механику работы сайта. Мне попалось это сообщение в очереди проверок и я решил, что качество вопроса оставляет желать лучшего, поэтому и оставил ссылку. В теме я не разбираюсь, потому и не ответил. Комментарии для того и существуют, чтобы указывать автору вопроса, что в вопросе не так. Если вам так никто и не ответил, заработайте 50 баллов репутации и задайте конкурсный вопрос.

Comment: И не понял, что вы подразумеваете под "набивать посты"? Я просто осуществлял премодерацию и все.